# Обрез строки без точек на конце?

Tags: html, css

Сейчас у меня такой код:

```
display: block;
white-space: nowrap;
overflow: hidden;
text-overflow: ellipsis;
```

Результат: обрез строки с точками. Как можно обрезать текст, что бы не было на конце точек?

Comment: почитайте о `text-overflow` - http://htmlbook.ru/css/text-overflow

Comment: я пробовал использовать clip, но оно не работате

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Обрезать без добавления точек:
text-overflow: clip

Или вообще не указывайте text-overflow, 
overflow:hidden просто не даст тексту вылезти за границы